# webpackPrefetch: true not generating link tag

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am using `import(/* webpackPrefetch: true */ "module");` inside my entry point `.js` file and based on the webpack docs it should generate a `<link rel=”prefetch”>` tag, but it doesn't show up even at runtime. Anybody got a clue why?

My files are being bundled correctly, `scripts` and `css` are injected just fine.

https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#prefetchingpreloading-modules

Answer (score 0):

> webpack will add the prefetch hint once the parent chunk has been loaded.

make sure the parent chunk has been loaded. the `<link rel=”prefetch”>` is inserted at runtime